# Access Report Incorrect Output

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a movies Database that includes movie titles, directors, nominations, wins, gross, etc.

I am supposed to create a report that shows the following:

- Include the director name, movie title, best picture, and best director.  Omit movies where both awards are null
- Group on the director name.  Sort by the title.  Print counts for the awards, and the sum of the two award counts.

My issue is that when I include the 4 things asked for, group them on director name, and sort by the title, I get an output with a report displaying each director name with EVERY movie in the database listed for EACH director.  Also, I do not get the option to print the counts or the sum.

Comment: Can you show us your current code?

Comment: You state this is an MS-Access report and have a tag of SQL..  Can you share please?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the 2 factors end up getting inlcuded in the GROUP BY (both Director and Movie Title). Since the field values you are measuring on (the two award types) are specific to each an every movie, you will always get the results you currently see, because it makes logical sense.

The objective of the report sounds problematic. The sums of the 2 award counts don't make sense if you include every Movie Title values. Should you not be removing the Movie Title values from the results (it is tricky for me to say without seeing the query or requirement)?